# Using Yoneda to establish natural isomorphisms?

Tags: category-theory, yoneda-lemma, natural-transformations

I know the Yoneda embedding can be used to easily establish isomorphisms between objects in categories. For example, in a locally small cartesian closed category $\mathbf{C}$ with coproducts, the "distributivity" isomorphism
$$(A\times B)+(A\times C)\cong A\times(B+C)\tag{1}$$
follows from the natural isomorphism
$$y((A\times B)+(A\times C))\cong y(A\times(B+C))\tag{2}$$
where $y:\mathbf{C}^{\mathrm{op}}\to\mathbf{Sets}^{\mathbf{C}}$ is the (contravariant) Yoneda embedding. The natural isomorphism (2) follows fairly easily from the universal properties of the relevant objects in $\mathbf{C}$.

Is it also possible to (easily) establish the *naturality* of the isomorphism (1) using the Yoneda embedding? For example, to show naturality in $A$? My initial thoughts are:

- If I can show, for $f:A\to A'$ in $\mathbf{C}$, commutativity of the *embedding* of the relevant naturality square, then naturality follows since the embedding is faithful. But this approach doesn't seem to make my life any easier. (Maybe for some problems it does?)
- If $\mathbf{C}$ is small, then $\mathbf{C}^{\mathbf{C}}$ is locally small, so I could consider the embedding $\mathbf{y}:(\mathbf{C}^{\mathbf{C}})^{\mathrm{op}}\to\mathbf{Sets}^{\mathbf{C}^{\mathbf{C}}}$ and try to establish a natural isomorphism $\mathbf{y}(F)\cong\mathbf{y}(G)$, where $F,G:\mathbf{C}\to\mathbf{C}$ are the functors (of $A$) on the left and right sides of (1). But this seems even more insane.
- If there is a "higher level" naturality relationship between the natural isomorphisms in (2), perhaps I could use that to easily establish naturality of (1). But I'm not sure if there is one, since I haven't studied much higher category theory yet.

It's also possible I'm missing something more obvious.

I ask because in Awodey's book *Category Theory*, 2nd ed., in Proposition 8.6 on p. 193, Awodey purports to establish the "canonical" isomorphism (1) using Yoneda. However, if "canonical" means natural, I don't see how that follows from his proof; and if "canonical" means something else, I don't know what he's talking about.

Comment: In my limited experience *canonical = from universal property $\Rightarrow$ natural*. In this case you have already established that you have a natural isomorphism of representables. Since the Yoneda embedding is full and faithful this should boil down to the corresponding naturality of the isomorphism between the representing objects. Yoneda makes your life easier, since (more or less by definition) universal properties come from natural isomorphisms to or between representables.

Comment: @PrudiiArca Thanks, but I'm still not totally clear on how (2) boils down to *naturality* of (1). Are you suggesting that (2) determines a UMP that both of the objects in (1) satisfy, so we know that the iso in (1) is canonical (uniquely determined by the UMP)? If so, can you elaborate?

Comment: It was rather meant along the lines of *faithful functors reflect commutative diagrams*. Drawing the commutativity square for (1) and applying the full and faithful Yoneda embedding, we should obtain the commuting naturality square for (2), hence (1) was commutative. I must admit though that I did not work out the details of this claim, which is why I didn’t give an answer.

Comment: @PrudiiArca Thanks. That's similar to what I had in mind in my first bullet point above, but note the embedding of the square for (1) is not the square for (2). The former square is in $\mathbf{Sets}^{\mathbf{C}}$ while the latter square is in $\mathbf{Sets}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working more problems, I see that the approach indicated in my first bullet point above *can* make my life easier, because it ultimately reduces the problem to showing commutativity of squares like
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\mathrm{Hom}(FA,X) @<{\cong}<< \mathrm{Hom}(GA,X)\\
@A (Ff)^* AA @AA (Gf)^* A\\
\mathrm{Hom}(FA',X) @<<{\cong}< \mathrm{Hom}(GA',X)
\end{CD}
and that is often not hard. Then the result follows by faithfulness of the Yoneda embedding (or by taking $X=GA'$ and chasing $1_{GA'}$ around the diagram).